# Sending email when an event occurs Thunderbird

Tags: javascript, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm a noob in developing extensions for Thunderbird. How can I send a letter when the event occurs with an attachment using javascript and Api Mozilla?

Answer (score 0):

Sending an email is a complex task for which a library exists (thunderbird-stdlib). See the code of the send function over there : https://github.com/protz/thunderbird-stdlib/blob/master/send.js#L452

You question is very much un-specific, so it's hard to reply properly, but documentation on Thunderbird is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/HowTos and general documentation for addons (much of which is applicable to thunderbird) is at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions

Best of luck,